# how to sort numbers in descending order which are attached to text within a cell

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

My Data is this CSI [40%], CSSEl [50%], LDN [10%] within one cell separated by comma. can any one help me with excel vba code which will sort percentages in descending order and provide me output as this: CSSEl [50%],CSI [40%],LDN [10%].

Comment: We _urgently_ need to see your coding attempt.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. unfortunately i am not sure how to tackle this hence my request if someone can help me code this

Comment: Although i know how to sort numbers in descending order but when it is prefixed with this name then i am not sure how to manage this.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for your prompt response. unfortunately i am not sure how to tackle this hence my request if someone can help me code this.Although i know how to sort numbers in descending order but when it is prefixed with this name then i am not sure how to manage this...I am in middle of a project which requires this..by any chance would you be able to help me Sir?

Comment: How many columns are there besides the column with the text and percents?

Comment: @user11060139 There are no columns besides this one column but i want apply this operation on multiple rows with each cell having a maximum of 7 such values. So Eg. my 1st row within one cell Data is this CSI [40%], CSSEl [50%], LDN [10%]. 2nd row within one cell data can be Data is this CSI [20%], CSSEl [50%], LDN [10%], ABC [20%] and so one...so my final out put in an additional column next to orginal will have all these values sorted by percentage in descenting order along with text affixed with them

Comment: @user11060139 in some cases values can be CSI [0%], CSSEL[100%] ---> REQUIRED OUTPUT IS  CSSEL[100%], CSI [0%]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you.

Add the below code into a new Module within VBA and then call the formula in a cell adjacent to your cell with the values.

So in the example below, your original values are in column **A** and the custom UDF in column **B** directly adjacent.

```
Public Function SortByInternalNumber(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strDelimiter As String)
    Dim arrValues() As String, strValue As String, i As Long, lngNumber As Long, arrNumbers() As String
    Dim strNumber As String, lngMaxNumber As Long, lngMaxIndex As Long, strResult As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean, arrMaxValues() As Long, lngIndex As Long, strMaxValue As String
    Dim strThisValue As String

    Application.Volatile

    ' Split up the initial string with all of the values.
    arrValues = Split(strText, strDelimiter)

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrValues)
        strValue = Trim(arrValues(i))

        strNumber = Replace(Replace(Split(strValue, "[")(1), "%", ""), "]", "")

        ReDim Preserve arrNumbers(i)
        arrNumbers(i) = strNumber
    Next

    ' Now process all of the numbers in the descending order.
    Do While 1 = 1
        lngMaxNumber = -1
        bFound = False

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrNumbers)
            If arrNumbers(i) <> "" Then
                lngNumber = CLng(arrNumbers(i))

                If lngMaxNumber < lngNumber Then
                    lngMaxNumber = lngNumber
                    lngMaxIndex = i
                End If

                bFound = True
            End If
        Next

        If Not bFound Then Exit Do
        lngIndex = -1

        ' Retrieve all of the values that are of the same value as the current max.
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrNumbers)
            If arrNumbers(i) <> "" Then
                If CLng(arrNumbers(i)) = lngMaxNumber Then
                    lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
                    ReDim Preserve arrMaxValues(lngIndex)
                    arrMaxValues(lngIndex) = i
                End If
            End If
        Next

        strMaxValue = ""

        ' Now do the same thing as above but instead of descending, do ascending.
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrMaxValues)
            strThisValue = Trim(arrValues(arrMaxValues(i)))

            If strMaxValue > strThisValue Or strMaxValue = "" Then
                strMaxValue = strThisValue
                lngMaxIndex = arrMaxValues(i)
            End If
        Next

        strResult = strResult & ", " & strMaxValue 
        arrNumbers(lngMaxIndex) = ""
    Loop

    If strResult <> "" Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, 3)
    End If

    SortByInternalNumber = Trim(strResult)
End Function
```

It's fairly rigid in but I have demonstrated that you can parameterize more of the relevant options.

[image]

I hope that makes sense and I hope it's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to create a helper column where you extract the numeric value. Assuming your data starts in A1, write a formula in column B like

```
=MID(A1, FIND("[", A1)+1, FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[", A1)-1)
```

With this, you can easily sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

May try another alternative

```
Sub testsort()
Dim txt As String, txt2 As String, Arr As Variant
Dim Nums() As Long, NumSort() As Long, i As Integer, k As Integer


txt = "CSI [40%], CSSEl [50%], LDN [10%], ABC [40%],ZXH[30%]"
Arr = Split(txt, ",")
ReDim Nums(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr))
ReDim NumSort(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr))
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Spos = InStr(1, Arr(i), "[")
    Epos = InStr(1, Arr(i), "%")
       If Spos > 0 And Epos > Spos Then
       Nums(i) = Val(Mid(Arr(i), Spos + 1, Epos - Spos - 1))
       Else
       Nums(i) = 0
       End If
    Next i


    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    NumSort(i) = LBound(Arr)
        For k = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            If Nums(i) < Nums(k) Or (Nums(i) = Nums(k) And k < i) Then
            NumSort(i) = NumSort(i) + 1
            End If
        Next
    Debug.Print Arr(i), Nums(i), NumSort(i)
    Next


    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)  ' rank
    For k = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    If NumSort(k) = i Then
    txt2 = txt2 & Arr(k) & ","
    Exit For
    End If
    Next k
    Next i

    If Len(txt2) > 0 Then txt2 = Left(txt2, Len(txt2) - 1) 'delete last comma
    Debug.Print txt2
End Sub
```